# ModSecurity : How prevent the body to be displayed in the JSON output?

Tags: apache2, mod-security

Using Modsecurity, I write the catched requests in a log, in a JSON format. The body field is too verbose for my ELK index, and generates a lot of parsing errors.

Can I disable the presence of the body in the JSON log ?

Comment: Are you logging directly to your ELK stack OR  to a log file and using something like filebeat or similar to read/tail that log file and send the events found  to your ELK?

Comment: I'm logging to a file, then rsyslog sends it to a server where logstash parse it and send it to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable [SecAuditLogParts](https://nature.berkeley.edu/%7Ecasterln/modsecurity/html-multipage/03-configuration-directives.html) can be set in **/etc/modsecurity.conf** :

eg :

```
SecAuditLogParts ABHJZ
```